# Upgrading from MassTransit v5 to v8 and an AutoFac Extension method used by our Multi Tenanted application is no longer available

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, scope, autofac, masstransit

In a nutshell I'm in the process of upgrading a .NETStandard 2.1 app to .NET 6.   Plus upgrading the various libraries accordingly, in particular MassTransit v5 to v8, and AutoFac 4.9.4 to 6.4.0.

This is a multi-tenant application where one instance is shared by multiple tenants, and each tenant has their own database.

The upgrade has gone well apart from one snag.  The application uses the, no longer available, AutofacReceivedEndpointExtensions to setup the Tenant details in the Consumer, and I am struggling to find a way to replicate the functionally it provides.

Below is the key bit of code.

```
config.ReceiveEndpoint(host, azureBusConfig.QueueName, endpoint =>
{                   
    ConfigureConsumer<MyConsumer>(endpoint, componentContext);                   
});

private static void ConfigureConsumer<TConsumer>(IServiceBusReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpoint, IComponentContext componentContext, Action<IConsumerConfigurator<TConsumer>> configure = null)
        where TConsumer : class, IConsumer
{
    endpoint.Consumer(componentContext, configure, configureScope: (container, context) =>
    {
        var tenantName = context.Headers.Get<string>("tenant");
        var userId = context.Headers.Get<int>("userId");
        container.RegisterInstance(new NamedTenantInfoProvider(tenantName, userId)).As<ITenantInfoProvider>();
    });
}
```

The endpoint.Consumer method as shown is no longer provided.

The ITenantInfoProvider interface is injected into various constructors in the application e.g., to setup the dbContext for a tenant to point to the correct database.

```
public interface ITenantInfoProvider
{
    string GetTenantName();
    int? GetUserId();
}
```

There are two implementations of the ITenantInfoProvider.   The NamedTenantInfoProvider which is used to set the Tenant from the received message, above.
There is also a RequestTenantInfoProvider, that gets the Tenant from the HttpRequest. e.g. via api call.
The RequestTenantInfoProvider is registered as follows

```
builder.RegisterType<RequestTenantInfoProvider>()
                .As<ITenantInfoProvider>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

So, what should happen is that the RequestTenantInfoProvider is injected into the constructors by default, but when a message is being consumed the NamedTenantInfoProvider instance is injected instead.

I have tried to register the NamedTenantInfoProvider as per the RequestTenantInfoProvider.  Then inject an IEnumerable into the constructors.  And set the Tenant in the consumer.ConfigureConsumer on the Named instance.   Then use which ever instance has a Tenant set in the code.   However, the NamedTenantInfoProvider instance is set after it is required in the other constructors e.g., dbContext.

The only way I can get the application to fully work is to hardcode a Tenant name in the NamedTenentInfoProvider class.

I was hoping that someone has already refactored some similiar code to replace the endpoint.ConfigureConsumer call and can advise a solution.
It may be that I'm missing a bit of knowledge regarding how scoping works with the Microsoft Dependency Injection/MassTransit configuration.   Note: I didn't write the original application, and this is my first dabble with Mass Transit as well.

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit v8 (and onward) only support `IServiceCollection`, which is part of *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection*. [Third-party containers](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/upgrade-v6.html#third-party-container-support) are no longer directly supported.

There is a [Scoped Filter](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters) sample that might help you understand how scopes work with MSDI. The token concept is similar to that used by developers injecting "tenant info" into consumers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the example has helped me move a step in the right direction.